# shortcodes are showing everywhere on single pages

Tags: wordpress-theming

i have created a shortcode for related posts in order to make it work. But when i apply it, it shows below post content. I want this to be shown only in related posts. the shortcode is like this.

```
add_shortcode( 'post_categories', 'openblogger_post_categories_shortcode' );


function openblogger_post_categories_shortcode( $atts ) {

$defaults = array(
    'sep'    => ', ',
    'before' => __( 'Filed Under: ', 'openblogger' ),
    'after'  => '',
);

$atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts, 'post_categories' );

$cats = get_the_category_list( trim( $atts['sep'] ) . ' ' );

// Do nothing if there are no categories.
if ( ! $cats ) {
    return '';
}

if ( openblogger_html5() ) {
    $output = sprintf( '<span %s>', categories_links() ) . $atts['before'] . $cats . $atts['after'] . '</span>';
} else {
    $output = '<span class="categories">' . $atts['before'] . $cats . $atts['after'] . '</span>';
}

return apply_filters( 'openblogger_post_categories_shortcode', $output, $atts );

}
```

i don't know why it is showing below the post content.